# Jquery Tools Overlay - Deep Linking

Tags: jquery, overlay

I have a webpage that has a page with many images that when clicked open separate JQuery Tools Overlays that display FlowPlayer videos.  We use these as tutorials of various features of the product my company offers.

What we're looking to do is in an email have a link that opens the website on the above page and automatically display the overlay (and therefor video) we require.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

I know with PrettyPhoto you can enable deeplinking to get the link, but what i can't figure out is how to do this with JQuery Tools Overlay.

Answer (score 0):

idea can be ike that:
In your e-mails you can add GET values to links like www.yoursite.com?prodid=15&image=image4
(I assume **id** of your trigger image that you want to show video is **image4**)
like

```
<img src="/some.jpg" id="image4"/>
```

and in your hard coding you need to GET it like that (PHP);

```
// js codes that will run when your DOM is ready
<? 
if ($_GET["image"]){ echo "$('#".$_GET["image"]."').click();";} 
?>
//rest of your js code
```

see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8CTt8/2/) for machanism (i mean you can fire element's trigger by click() method)